# Does a processor ‘know’ that there is a cache in the computer system?

Tags: cache

I think with general purpose processors it would just go straight to the memory (let me know if I'm wrong), and the processor won't be bothered if or not there is a cache. What happens with DSPs?

Comment: A prosessor knows nothing.  It is a free spirit that lives in the moment created by the previous command and the present command.  Aside from that, it knows nothing of what came before or what comes next.  It waits for an instruction to be in the queue, whether that is one clock cycle or infinity.

Comment: The system programmer had better know!   Without a forced cache flush, any change in how something is being accessed may otherwise fail, eg, write as data then try to execute, in the case of distinct caches.  Or mixing CPU and DMA access.  Or in some cases, multi processor designs.

Answer (score 2):

The processor's load/store hardware is directly connected to the first level of cache, which is connected to the next, which is connected to the next and so on.  Typically accesses to memory are only triggered when the last level of cache misses.

This is important because values in cache may be more up to date than values in memory, so loading memory without checking the cache could return the wrong value.

This applies to CPUs and DSPs alike, although DSPs are more likely to have a way for the programmer to bypass the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside StainlessSteelRat's question of what it means for a processor to "know" something, the answer for Intel is that it definitely *does* know.

Intel processors access via [CPUID.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283171/how-to-receive-l1-l2-l3-cache-size-using-cpuid-instruction-in-x86)

ARM has its own [cache size information register.](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0388/e/the-system-control-coprocessors/summary-of-system-control-coprocessor-registers/cache-size-identification-register)

Additionally, many processors can turn the use of cache on and off. It's not unusual to be able to use the cache as RAM early on in the boot sequence - with no DRAM backing it at all. This is useful for BIOS code which wants to detect and "train" the DRAM.

However, at the level of individual instruction execution, whether or not the cache was involved is not directly visible.

Comment: All of the (few) processors that I've worked with or read up on that have cache have finer-grained manipulation of the thing that just on and off.  The most useful features for me have been to manually flush or fetch cache lines (to make sure that memory-mapped I/O or shared memory actually interacts "out there"), and to lock down cache lines for oft-used and speed-critical sections of memory.